# Cannot delete column with only null values when BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, blue-green-deployment

I'm using a **blue-green deployment** strategy with **expand contract database pattern**. To achieve that on my database deploy schema I've setted the property **BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true** because on **Expand phase** I can modify my database without any break change with the old version.
[image]

I had a column that is not necessary anymore so I followed those steps:

1. I've changed this column to allow null values
2. Then my new records don't fill this column anymore
3. I ran a script that setted null for this column to all table records

Now I need to delete this column, but even with all records with NULL value for this column I can't because I got this error:

> Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss
> might occur.'

How can I delete this column even using **BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true**?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the table with the new schema (without the column you wan't to drop) with a temporary name. Something like `tmp_YourTable` (Not a temporary table)
2. Insert all data from the source table, to the newly created table
3. Drop the source table
4. Rename the new table, to the old table name. `EXEC sp_rename 'tmp_YourTable', 'YourTable';`